# using apache Flask application is not reading configuarion file

Tags: python, apache, flask

In one of the flask module I am reading data from .cnf file like below
I am accessing file like below

```
os.path.join('.','test.cfg'), os.path.join('.','test1.cfg')
```

using normal run.py its picks it correctly.
while using apache i belive it is not able to pick the file.

Where should i place these files.
on application root folder. its not able to find?

update:
I am using wsgi

i have corrected code like below . Is this pythonic?

```
dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(file)) os.path.join(dir,'test.cfg'), os.path.join(dir,'test1.cfg'))
```

Comment: It seems like the obvious question is "how are you running Flask?" wsgi? Proxy server? cgi? Other?

Comment: The current directory `'.'` will be different no matter what you're using to run the app. So either use absolute paths (not recommended) or `os.path.realpath(__file__)` to set the base path of the app.

Comment: Yeah, not bad. Should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current directory `'.'` will be different no matter what you're using to run the app. So either use absolute paths (not recommended) or `os.path.realpath(__file__)` to set the base path of the app.

Answer (score 3):

Read the mod_wsgi documentation on this topic:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Application_Working_Directory